# Next.js 14 Server Actions: Issue Modifying Cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript

I'm currently developing a Next.js 14 application and have encountered an issue with modifying cookies. Despite following the Next.js documentation on server actions and cookie manipulation, I'm receiving an error when trying to set cookies during the signout process.
The error message states: "Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my project:

```js
// pwa/src/utils/globalActions.ts

'use server';

import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export const signout = async () => {
  cookies.set('token', '', { maxAge: -1 });
  cookies.set('refreshToken', '', { maxAge: -1 });
  cookies.set('user', '', { maxAge: -1 });
  return redirect('/auth/signin');
};
```

```js
// pwa/src/utils/apiAxios.ts (This file is used by both client and server components)

import axios, {
    type AxiosResponse,
    type AxiosError,
    type AxiosInstance,
} from 'axios';
import { signout } from './globalActions';

const Axios = axios.create({
    baseURL: ENTRYPOINT,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/ld+json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/ld+json',
    },
});

Axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    async (error: AxiosError<ApiResponseError>) => {
        if (error.status === 401 || error.response?.status === 401) {
            await signout();
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    },
);
```

I've checked my usage against the Next.js documentation and made sure to use the server execution context ('use server';). Yet, the issue persists. I suspect I might be missing a detail in how Next.js 14 handles cookies in server actions or there might be a specific configuration step I've overlooked.

Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone have insights on how to properly modify cookies within server components in Next.js 14?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler.

this message indicates that you should be on the server side but as far as I know `axios.interceptors.response` gets called immediately after axios receives a response from the server and before the promise returned by the Axios request is resolved.

so you are calling `cookies.set` after request is exectuted on the server

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm confused: According to the [https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations#server-components](NextJS documentation for server-side operations), we can invoke a server action from a server component.
Therefore, when calling axios from a server component, the `axios.interceptors.response` should also be executed within a server component, allowing me to initiate a server action for modifying cookies.

Answer (score 0):

When `signout` is called within an Axios interceptor, it is not guaranteed to run in a server action or route handler context, and thus, you cannot modify cookies there.You can create a server action that performs the signout and sets the cookies accordingly, and then call this server action from the client side when required.

Restructure globalActions.ts:

```
'use server';

import { createServerAction, redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export const signoutServerAction = createServerAction(async () => {
  // Set cookies maxAge to -1 to expire them
  cookies.set('token', '', { maxAge: -1 });
  cookies.set('refreshToken', '', { maxAge: -1 });
  cookies.set('user', '', { maxAge: -1 });

  // Redirect to the sign-in page
  return redirect('/auth/signin');
});
```

On the client side, you would trigger this server action when needed:

```
// Trigger this function when you want to signout
const triggerSignout = async () => {
  await signoutServerAction();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but createServerAction does not exist (I'm using NextJS 14.1.0). As expected, the results are consistent with my initial code, with the only difference being the `triggerSignout` function, which, in my scenario, is called within the Axios Interceptor.